# Cannot uninstall "Giara" Application. Installed it via Snap Store. How to force-uninstall it?

Tags: 22.04, uninstall, snap, appmenu, snap-store

[Click here to view a detailed explanation of the problem with screen recording.](https://ufile.io/w7x64ty5)
[image: Image of Problem]
I installed Giara app from the Snap Store. Now I can't run it, so I obviously want to uninstall it, but I can't do so as it reports no application found, even though it is listed in the "Installed Apps" section in Snap Store. Please help me to remove it.

Comment: Did you try `sudo snap remove giara`? What does `snap list` show?

Comment: @ArturMeinild I did and it shows no package found. In list also there is no "Giara" app.

Comment: Then it would seem the app is removed  then it's a graphical issue in the GUI store, The actual app have been removed (which is also in line with the error message you get).

Comment: the graphical store is a bit bad at caching. So yeah, you're seeing an old state. Sounds like the software you wanted to remove has gone, and you can probably confirm this by killing and restarting the graphical store.

Comment: @popey Thank you, restarting helped me sort it out!